# splice in a loop to update new array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
let index = findIndex(existingObjs, { '_id': data.id });
if (index > -1) {
    existingObjs.splice( index, 1, newObj );
}
```

Above code is working to replace updated obj after a PUT. But I have problem doing so if the newObj is an array and has multiple object.

Comment: Can we see the code for `existingObjs`? Also --- are you trying to overwrite an object? or put a new one in between others?

Answer (score 0):

From what it seems you are trying to `remove one` and add multiple objects from the obj array `newObj` , you can do that using the `spread operator`.

Do it in the following manner

```
let index = findIndex(existingObjs, { '_id': data.id });
if (index > -1) {
    existingObjs.splice( index, 1, ...newObj );
}
```